# Grails integration testing of internationalized REST calls

Tags: rest, grails, internationalization, integration-testing

I am trying to test internationalization from integration tests for a grails controller. 
The controller is REST enabled and returns JSON responses.

In order to test internationalization, one can simply give ?lang=es in the URL and the respective message bundle is used internally by grails.

I am in a support project where the internationalization already works as it is supposed to. When I give a curl request, I receive the responses in the correct languages.

The integration test is just intended to validate the different language specific responses.

I am not sure how I can request for any language from the integration test.

I tried :

1. response.locale = new Locale("es", "es") //did not work
2. controller.params.lang = "es" // did not work

I have not found much help on this from http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html#changingLocales. And neither from other questions but A related article could be [How to unit or integration test use of injected messageSource for i18n in Grails 2.0 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134520/how-to-unit-or-integration-test-use-of-injected-messagesource-for-i18n-in-grails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration tests use the `GrailsMockHttpServletRequest` class that have the method `addPreferredLocale(Locale)` to change the locale of the current test request.

Normally we get the request through `RequestContextHolder`:

```
def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
request.addPreferredLocale(new Locale("pt","BR"))
```

Comment: Thank you. This however does not seem to work for me. My debugging continues.