# i18n in Grails Integration Test

Tags: grails, internationalization, integration-testing

Supposing I have a controller method that uses i18n to set `flash.message`

```
def someMethod(){
  // ...
  flash.message = message(code: 'label.generic.delete.ok.message', default: 'Delete OK')
  // ...
}
```

When I want to write an **integration test** to test this controller, I can't seem to find how to test the value of that message.

My problem is that I do not want to hard code the message in the test by doing something like this

```
assert controller.flash.message == "Delete successfull"
```

I'd rather do something like this

```
assert controller.flash.message == message(code: 'label.generic.delete.ok.message')
```

This throws a `groovy.lang.missingMethodException`.

I've looked at [other answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134520/how-to-unit-or-integration-test-use-of-injected-messagesource-for-i18n-in-grails) but the only solutions were given for unit tests.

I'm using `grails 2.2.4`.

**Does anyone know how to access `message()` in integration tests?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test i18 messages in integration test as:

inject the bean `messageSource` in test spec and call `getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale)`

Here

**code**: to lookup up, such as 'calculator.noRateSet' and

**args**: Array of arguments that will be filled in for params within the message in your case it can be set as `null` and

**locale**: the Locale in which to do the lookup
e.g

```
messageSource.getMessage('calculator.noRateSet', null, controller.request.getLocale())
```