# Instance of MessageSource in a test controller (calling a service that calls a MessageSource.)

Tags: grails, spock

I am using grails 2.3.6 and I am trying to test a controller that calls a service that calls a MessageSource. I have tried all solutions in this post ([How to unit or integration test use of injected messageSource for i18n in Grails 2.0 service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9134520/5393947)) but I am still getting this error:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'enrolment.state.approved' for locale 'es_ES'.
    at es.portel.accessRequest.enyca.EnrolmentClientService.enrolmentTranslateState(EnrolmentClientService.groovy:30)
    at es.portel.accessRequest.enyca.EnrolmentClientService.enromentsTranslateState_closure1(EnrolmentClientService.groovy:13)
    at es.portel.accessRequest.enyca.EnrolmentClientService.enromentsTranslateState(EnrolmentClientService.groovy:12)
    at es.portel.accessRequest.enyca.EnrolmentClientController.getAllEnrolments(EnrolmentClientController.groovy:41)
    at es.portel.accessRequest.enyca.EnrolmentClientControllerSpec.test getAllEnrolments method(EnrolmentClientControllerSpec.groovy:34)
```

This is my test code:

```
@TestFor(EnrolmentClientController)
 @Mock(EnrolmentClientService)
 class EnrolmentClientControllerSpec extends Specification{
    void "test getAllEnrolments method"() {
       given:
       MessageSource messageSource = getMessageSource()
       controller.enrolmentClientService = new EnrolmentClientService()
       controller.enrolmentClientService.messageSource = messageSource
       Locale locale1 = new Locale("es_ES")
       messageSource.addMessage('enrolment.state.approved',locale1, 'Aprobado')

       when:
       controller.getAllEnrolments()

       then:
       assertEquals response.status,  HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
       assertEquals response.format, 'json'
       }
   }
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your are unit test `EnrolmentClientController` and mock your `EnrolmentClientService` therefore you cannot use `new EnrolmentClientService()` since it is mocked by Grails. Try to remove that line

Comment: It doesn't work, still getting the same error. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few headaches, I have finally solved. I took off the Mock Service as saw303 told me and a proper setup. This is the working code:

```
@TestFor(EnrolmentClientController)
class EnrolmentClientControllerSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    def messageSource = new StaticMessageSource()

    def setupSpec() {
        Locale locale1 = new Locale("es_ES")
        messageSource.useCodeAsDefaultMessage = true
        messageSource.addMessage "enrolment.state.approved", locale1, "Aprobado"
    }


    void "test getAllEnrolments method"() {
       given:
       controller.enrolmentClientService = new EnrolmentClientService()
       controller.enrolmentClientService.messageSource = messageSource

       when:
       request.method = 'GET'
       response.format = 'json'
       controller.getAllEnrolments()
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad this works for you. But since your are unit testing your unit test should only test the behaviour of your controller. In an ideal case the controllers service dependency is mocked. The scenario you want to test is better suited by writing an integration test. In that case you don't have to mock the message source and you test your controller in integration with your service.